# SOQL inside the For loop

Tags: apex, soql

We are creating opportunity and line items by APEX code from Rate cards and the jobs(custom objects). As part of the code, we are doing a validation to see if the Ready_for_Billing__c field in jobs (corresponding to the rate card) have been checked to true else we want to update the flag Ready_for_Billing_error__c on the rate card to False.

Can someone help me to rewrite the below code to avoid SOQL inside the for loop?  Thanks in advance!

```
List<sked__Job__c> joblist=new List<sked__Job__c>();
List<Rate_Card__c> Rcardnew =[select Id,Job_Type__c,Last_Opportunity_Creation_Date__c,
                                     Next_Opportunity_Creation_Date__c,Account__c 
                                from Rate_Card__c
                               where (Opportunity_Creation_Date__c!=NULL OR 
                                      Next_Opportunity_Creation_Date_Error__c!=NULL)
                                 and Rate_Card_Type__c='Pain Management' 
                                 and Is_Active__c=true and Account__c=:account 
                                 AND Opportunity_Creation_Frequency__c='Weekly'];

if(Rcardnew.size()>0)
{
    for(Rate_Card__c rcard:Rcardnew)
    {
        joblist=[select id from sked__Job__c  
                  where Invoice_Start__c>=:rcard.Last_Opportunity_Creation_Date__c 
                    and Invoice_Finish__c<=:rcard.Next_Opportunity_Creation_Date__c 
                    and sked__Account__c=:rcard.Account__c 
                    and sked__Job_Status__c='Complete' 
                    and Job_Invoiced__c=false and sked__Type__c=:rcard.Job_Type__c 
                    and Ready_for_Billing__c=FALSE 
                    and Facility_Patient_Sevices_Count__c<=0];

        if(joblist.size()>0)
        {
            try
            {
                rcard.Ready_for_Billing_error__c=TRUE;
                update rcard;
            }
            catch(DMLException e)
            {
                //handled exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey please avoid using queries in for loop in above code you have using joblist in a for loop please try to use out of the for loop and try to search in google @Mani

Comment: Pavan, that's what the OP needs help with. "Search in Google" is something that we all can do, he just needed to be helped, not to be told to search.

Comment: is there a schema relationship between Sked_Job__c and Rate_Card__c?

Comment: @cropredy: nope, there is no schema relationship between Sked_Job__c and Rate_Card__c. They are related based on the condition that I have given in the code above.

Comment: is `account` a singleton or a list (of Accounts)

Comment: @cropredy account is a singleton..

Answer (score 0):

```
List<sked__Job__c> joblist=new List<sked__Job__c>();
List<sked__Job__c> jobsortedlist = new List<sked__Job__c>();
List<Rate_Card__c> Rcardnew =[select Id,Job_Type__c,Last_Opportunity_Creation_Date__c,
                                     Next_Opportunity_Creation_Date__c,Account__c 
                                from Rate_Card__c
                               where (Opportunity_Creation_Date__c!=NULL OR 
                                      Next_Opportunity_Creation_Date_Error__c!=NULL)
                                 and Rate_Card_Type__c='Pain Management' 
                                 and Is_Active__c=true and Account__c=:account 
                                 AND Opportunity_Creation_Frequency__c='Weekly'];

joblist=[Select id from sked__Job__c  
                             Where sked__Job_Status__c='Complete' AND
                                 Ready_for_Billing__c=FALSE  AND 
                                Facility_Patient_Sevices_Count__c<=0];


if(!Rcardnew.isNotEmpty() && joblist.isNotEmpty()){
    for(Rate_Card__c rcard:Rcardnew) {
        for(sked__Job__c job:joblist){
            if(job.Invoice_Start__c >= rcard.Last_Opportunity_Creation_Date__c && 
                job.Invoice_Finish__c <=rcard.Next_Opportunity_Creation_Date__c && 
                job.sked__Account__c==rcard.Account__c && 
                job.Job_Invoiced__c=false and sked__Type__c==rcard.Job_Type__c  ){
                jobsortedlist.add(rcard);
             }
        }
    }

     if(jobsortedlist >0)
        {
            try
            {  for(Rate_Card__c rcard:Rcardnew) 
                rcard.Ready_for_Billing_error__c=TRUE;
                update rcard;
            }
            catch(DMLException e)
            {
                //handled exception
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I have tested it and it works fine(creates opty and line items as jobs)

Comment: @pavantej: I am doing an order by when I query the rate card and job since both are related by the job type.

Comment: @cropredy: I have amended the original question, thx!

Comment: This has some issues: (1) - DML inside of for loop; (2) `if(jobsortedlist >0)` won't compile (missing `.size()` - and besides, is superfluous. (3) `
if(!Rcardnew.isNotEmpty() && joblist.isNotEmpty())` is also wrong/typo (double negative0 and the whole line is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

So, to address your specific concern, some logic like this should suffice: (I renamed `account` to be `aId` to be clearer)

```
Sked_Job__c[] jobList = [select ... from Sked_Job__c where sked_account__c = :aId];

Rate_card__c[] rcUpdList = new List<Rate_Card__c> ();
for (Rate_card__c rc : [select ... from Rate_Card__c where account__c = :aId ...)
   for (Sked_job__c sj : jobList)
      if (conditional logic to see if sj matches rc for billing error criteria) {
         rcUpdList.add(new Rate_card__c(id = rc.id, ready_for_billing_error__c = true));
         break;
      }

update rcUpdList;
```

However, I would suspect that this little routine fits inside of something larger that is (or should be) bulkified since you would presumably want to process many Rate Cards in a batch, each with a different account.  If so, you're going to need to rethink all of this so that the routine is passed a list of accounts - and the soql for jobList and Rate Cards fetch all ratecards and all `sked_Job__c` for all accounts.  But, we'll leave that for another day after you digest and learn from this.